# TimeoutError [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time

Tags: django, email, timeout, reset-password

I wanna sent a email to users account to reset password. But whenever I enter the send it causes an error.

> TimeoutError at /accounts/reset_password/
> [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

I do not know why I am having a lot of issue in doing **reset password**.
Things which I have done or try

- I already enable "less secure" apps in my gmail account.
- I was also having a issue in password_reset_email.html
  and for that I use
  email_template_name=accounts/registration/password_reset_email.html
  and after adding this the error was **TemplateDoesNotExist**. And then I make a dir in my accounts app and add a password_reset_email.html

Here is code. any help please

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, reverse_lazy
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [

    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
    path('signin/', views.signin, name='signin'),
    path('logout/', views.logout, name='logout'),

    path('user_profile/', views.edit_profile, name='edit_profile'),
    path('user_password/', views.change_password, name='change_password'),

    # Reset password section

    path('reset_password/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
             template_name='accounts/password_reset.html',
             success_url=reverse_lazy('accounts:password_reset_done'),
             email_template_name='accounts/registration/password_reset_email.html'
         ),
         name='reset_password'),


    path('reset_password_sent/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
             template_name='accounts/password_reset_sent.html',
         ),
         name='password_reset_done'),


    path('reset_confirm/<uidb64>/<token>',
         auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
             template_name='accounts/password_reset_form.html',
             success_url=reverse_lazy('accounts:password_reset_complete')
         ),
         name='password_reset_confirm'),


    path('rest_password_complete/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(
             template_name='accounts/password_reset_done.html',
         ),
         name='password_reset_complete')
]
```

**settings.py**

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend' 

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '*******'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*******'
```